# Spring JPA how to make sure that data gets written into persistent storage

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to extend this example: https://github.com/scratches/jpa-method-security-sample by adding a method in the controller to "signup" where a new user is dynamically added to the repo. The default set of existing users is added in the import.sql script. However, I see that my dynamically added user gets wiped out on server restart. Could you point me out the way to make sure the table gets updated persistently.

Here is my code for the signup method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "signup",method =  RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signup(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("message","Sign up!");
        model.put("title", "Hello Signup");
        model.put("date", new Date());
        users.createUser();
        return "signup";
    }

 public void createUser() {
    User u = new User();
    u.setName("xxx");
    u.setPassword("spring");
    repo.save(u);
}
```

I have also made changes to `loadUserByUserName` to return the correct authorities for the new user. This works fine for one server session and I can log in with the new user. However, on server restart, the user needs to be re-added. I want to prevent this.

I have a feeling that I need to do something more elaborate like configuring a persistent datasource. If that is the case, could you please point me to some resource that uses java config to do this. I am just starting on spring and this may be a basic question and of everything that I read, I am not sure what to follow.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using an embedded in-memory H2 database data does not persist across restarts. You should move away from the embedded DB, and since the app is based on [spring-boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), you can easily reconfigure this and use e.g. mysql, by adding mysql dependency to the pom.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and appropriate DB properties inside *application.properties* e.g.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/[YOUR DB]
spring.datasource.username=[YOUR USERNAME]
spring.datasource.password=[YOUR PASSWORD]
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Another thing to keep in mind, certain defaults are specific for embedded DBs such as the H2 DB. For example, the [`ddl-auto` property is set to `create-drop`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties).

This means that the DB schema will be created when the SessionFactory is created and dropped when it is closed.

The value of this property for e.g. MySql is set to *none* by default, this means that you'll have to initially run your application overriding the property (settting it inside *application.properties*)

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create
```

this will initially create the data from the *import.sql*. After the first start, change the property to *update*, and you'll data will persist across restart

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly. I set up MySql created the db and incorporated all the changes.. Just one question. If I want to do something similar in my actual gradle based project, I should add a dependency such as:http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.6 given under gradle right?

Comment: np, glad it helped, and for what concerns your question, yeps, just use the gradle dependency syntax

Comment: Sorry, but when I try to do something similar in my gradle project, I am getting an issue. My H2 based project is here: https://github.com/devdeep1987/MutiboProject/tree/master/MutiboServer. I removed the h2 dependecy inthe build.gradle and added  compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6") and added the properties in the application.properties but on launching, I get an error which I pasted here: http://pastebin.com/4cS9Dk0U. Was wondering if I need to do something more to configure the mysql dependency

Comment: I checked, I get the same error if I do not add any h2/mysql dependency in build.gradle which means, its not taking the mysql dependency at all.