# springboot read/write into real resources folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resources

I am trying to read and write files directly in my source resources folder.

Watching other questions like [Spring Boot access static resources missing scr/main/resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371748/spring-boot-access-static-resources-missing-scr-main-resources) I have been able to get the outputfolder by using `ClassPathResource`:

> out/resources/sql

Is it possible to get the real resources folder?

> /src/test/resources/sql

(I need it for test, thats why I wrote /test/, but I assume that solution for /main/ would also help me)

**Note**

I understand that for reading it's not a problem, since in runtime I will have anything under src/test/resources. However, for writing it will get overriden everytime I compile the code

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be /src/test/resources/sql? I wanted to persist data across server restarts and ended up configuring it to use a MySQL database instead. That way, I had access to it even when the Tomcat server that Spring runs on was stopped, and I could read from that same MySQL database when it's restarted.

I answered my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53254093/10305169) with the steps to take, based on an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28003702/spring-jpa-how-to-make-sure-that-data-gets-written-into-persistent-storage/28004042#28004042). Does that help?

Comment: Yeah, I need to save it into the file system, ddbb is not an option in this case